How can KEDA customize each scaled container instance?
I'd like to add some form of identity per container that is started by KEDA. For example, each container could get access to a different S3 bucket. How can I do it?
Illustrative scenario: dynamic virus analysis in a given container. I want to provide ability for container to report results, but I want to give it per-container S3 bucket, otherwise one virus could taint all other virus data. Ideally I'd like to somehow tell KEDA something like "next container started needs to get this as environment variable".
Since I am just learning about KEDA, it could be that the answer is "don't use KEDA for this".
I see https://keda.sh/docs/1.5/concepts/authentication/, but that seems to deal with KEDA authentication against data stores and not giving identity to the containers.

How would the per container s3 bucket be provisioned? Maybe the startup script of your container can create a new bucket, assign it to an env var and the container can start with it? KEDA doesn't really seem relevant here.

An outside process would prepare the S3 bucket with the starting virus in it, then prepare an access string for it. So, if I would like to somehow inform KEDA to "start the next container with this special environment variable".

KEDA is only responsible for deciding when to scale. From that point onwards it hands over the number to the native Kubernetes HPA which does the actual scaling. KEDA does not start any actual pods or have any control over them so this is not possible.

I'd promote your comment to an answer if I could.
